# dimension of a tensor created by tf.zeros(n)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm confused by the dimension of a tensor created with `tf.zeros(n)`. For instance, if I write: `tf.zeros(6).eval.shape`, this will return me `(6, )`. What dimension is this? is this a matrix of 6 rows and arbitrary # of columns? Or is this a matrix of 6 columns with arbitrary # of rows?

`weights = tf.random_uniform([3, 6], minval=-1, maxval=1, seed=1)`- this is `3X6` matrix

`b=tf.zeros(6).eval`- I'm not sure what dimension this is.

Why I am able to add the two like `weights+b`? If I understand correctly, in order for the two to be added, `b` needs to be `3X1` dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*why i am able to add the two like `weights+b`?*

Operator `+` is the same as using `tf.add()` (`<obj>.__add__()` calls the `tf.add()` or `tf.math.add()`) and if you read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add) it says:

> NOTE: math.add supports broadcasting. AddN does not. More about broadcasting [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Now I'm quoting from `numpy` broadcasting rules (which are the same for `tensorflow`):

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

So you're able to add two tensors with different shapes because they have the same trailing dimensions. If you change the dimension of your `weights` tensor to, let's say `[3, 5]`, you will get `InvalidArgumentError` exception because trailing dimensions differ.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, what is a trailing dimension?

Comment: @MeiNanZhu last dimension

Answer (score 0):

(6,) is python syntax for a tuple with 6 as a single element. Hence the shape here is a uni-dimensional vector of length 6.

Comment: hi, i just made my question more complete. please take a look again. thank you.